# Search text in pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, acrobat-sdk

can someone tell me if  AcrobatAccessLib (Acrobat Access 3.0 Type Library) in com references can be used for text searching in pdf document? 
It contains class PDDom, but I dont know if I can load document into it or, how to work with it.

(I dont wanna use iTextSharp, and others, I tryied it but not works as I wanted - pdf has corrupted number paging + contains tables, that are across 2 pages - iTextSharp finds me searching text on both pages - instead of 1, but if I use Acrobat Reader - it works well)

EDIT: Or another question, Can I use acrobat reader and its searching module in my application?

I am working in c#

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use PDFLIBNET.DLL

in that dll have pdfwrapper class, this class provides lots methods to get text from pdf. The FindText method used to get a text from a particular position, and exportToText method gives content of pdf page

from that content u will search the pdf content..

am using tat DLL and searching the pdf content with out any issue..

try it and let me know..

Comment: there are functions for text search, but how can I get number of page where text was found? f.e -  int c = a.FindFirst("A9F03102", PDFLibNet.PDFSearchOrder.PDFSearchFromdBegin, false, true); c=1 but this text is on 68 page

Comment: k.. use exportTotext method which gives full pdf text, here u search the text from startpage to endpage, between the for loop u 'll find the text on page..

Answer (score 1):

If money is not an issue, I would by the Aspose PDF components. They work pretty well and are built for server usage.